# Validating Custom Field

Tags: wordpress

How can I validate WordPress custom fields without using Javascript. I want to validate them using PHP and stop post creation on error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the hook [**`save_post`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post). There are lots of examples in WordPress Answers, check the results for [`+save_post +update_post_meta is:answer`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2bsave_post%20%2bupdate_post_meta%20is%3aanswer).

If it doesn't validate, use [**`wp_die()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) and the post won't be saved.